# Measured Drain to Source Peak Voltage seems very high on PoE circuit

Tags: poe

I am looking at TI's PMP20878 [test results](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidudb0/tidudb0.pdf?cm_session=92b0aacd-d1bc-43f1-ab54-cd87b3c554a8&cm_type=link&cm_link=06a3d91e-6cbc-4c1c-a645-77d364a05adb&utm_campaign=92b0aacd-d1bc-43f1-ab54-cd87b3c554a8&utm_medium=email&utm_source=contactmonkey&utm_content=sales%201%3A1&utm_term=RE%3A%20Simulation) found on their website. Based on the schematic I am very confused how the Drain to Source peak voltage can be much greater than the typical PoE input of 48V.

[Full Schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrrg3b/tidrrg3b.pdf)

For example:

For Q16, how is the peak drain to source voltage 126.7V??
[image: For Q16, how is the peak drain to source voltage 126.7V??]

For Q13 how is the peak drain to source voltage 90V??
[image: For Q13 how is the peak drain to source voltage 90V??]

Am I missing a principle related to the transformer T2??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an active clamp flyback converter.  During the switch (Q16) off time the secondary voltage appears across the primary winding scaled by the turns ratio.

That adds to the input voltage.  Finally, the active clamp capacitor charges from the leakage inductance and eventually pushes the drain voltage even higher.  So the peak voltage will be the sum of the three.